# How do I set the view angle of a sphere cast and also read the angle at which the objects are present in front of it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, angle, raycasting

this is what i want to achieve
[image: this is what i want to achieve]

I am currently trying to build a RADAR sensor on unity. I am currently using spherecast. How do i set the view angle of the sphere cast and also how do i read the angle at which an object is present in front of it.

What i have used now is `Vector3.angle` but this shows 160 degrees if the object is directly infront of the radar instead it should be showing 90 degrees.

Ill paste the code that i have implemented below
Any guidance is appreciated.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spherecast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    public List<GameObject> CurrentHitObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    //public GameObject curobject;

    public float radius;
    public float maxdist;
    public LayerMask layermask;
    public float velocity;
    public Time deltatime;
    public Vector3 previous;

    private Vector3 origin;
    private Vector3 direction;

    private float hitdist;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (GameObject cur in CurrentHitObjects)
        {
            previous = cur.transform.position;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        origin = transform.position;
        direction = transform.forward;

        hitdist = maxdist;
        CurrentHitObjects.Clear();

        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.SphereCastAll(origin, radius, direction, maxdist, layermask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);
        foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
        {
            Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main);
            if (GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, hit.collider.bounds))
            {
                float angle = Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, hit.point.normalized);
                float degree = Mathf.Acos(angle) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                Vector3 pos = hit.point;
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.name + "position =" + pos);
                CurrentHitObjects.Add(hit.transform.gameObject);
                hitdist = hit.distance;
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name + "Distance ="+ hitdist);
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.name + "Angle = " + angle);

                velocity = ((hit.transform.position - previous).magnitude) / Time.deltaTime;
                previous = hit.transform.position;
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name + "Velocity =" + velocity);
            }
            else
            {
                return ;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Debug.DrawLine(origin, origin + direction * hitdist);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(origin + direction * hitdist, radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "view angle of the sphere cast"?

Comment: This is definitely not how I would do it. I would create a sphere, and on collision enter add the game objects to a list. Then every 10 seconds or so iterate through the list and find the transform rotation to look at each of them. Then boom, you have your x and y change easy. Ray cast is overkill.

Comment: ill attach an image of what i mean @Draco18s

Comment: Your image doesn't help explain anything.

Comment: View angle is similar to the field of view of a camera but it needs to be in only one plane..Do you see the red lines that is the angle id like to define from the center of the spherecast. @Draco18s

Comment: `SphereCast(Vector3 origin, float radius, Vector3 direction, ...)` Hmm. `direction` probably has something to do with what you want. Have you tried [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180874/convert-angle-radians-to-a-heading-vector)?

Comment: Got it to work. I combined camera for field of view and shperecast.  now it only detects the objects within the cameras field of view]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your code doesn't do anything. My first tip would be to remove all of your commented out code, but after that here is why your code does nothing at all:

You pass an array of objects to your script. Fine so far.

1. You take this entire array of objects 'CurrentHitObjects' and pass the transform.position of every single object to a single vector3. This means that all the values are overwritten except for the last one. This would be a big problem if you were trying to find the position of every single object. This would instead require vector3[]. But there is another bigger problem.
2. 'previous', which holds transform.position of the objects is not used anywhere. So you are not actually finding the location of anything.
3. You use start() (which only runs once by the way) to iterate through your object array, but then you clear, CurrentHitObjects.Clear();, right at the beginning of update() (which runs many times per second by the way). The problem here, is that if you hoped to use CurrentHitObjects for anything in your code, you can't because you have wiped it before you even start doing anything with it.
4. Your raycast[] is shooting towards nothing. Seems to me like it just shoots forward.
5. You are finding the angle between the forward direction and the forward direction?

Honestly there are a lot of major problems with this code. I don't mean to be harsh, but it looks like you copy and pasted someone else's code and don't know how to use it. This needs a complete rework. If you know how to code I would throw it out and start over again. See my comment on your answer for a better way to do what you want.

If you don't know how to code, you should not be asking for freebie working code on stackoverflow. Try a unity forum instead. If you are trying to get better, see my above comments.

Comment: Hey Tyler Thank for the pointers man!! trying to implement what u had mentioned in your comment. I apologize for a lot of junk in the code. I actually did some parts of it following a tutorial. previous was used to find out the velocity of the object, which was working correctly. But it is not being used now